# looping element's list to create a carousel without jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a loop that goes through my image list whilst adding the children to the front, thereby forming a slide. However, it is not working. I wonder what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.images');
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('LI');
setInterval(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= imgs.length; i++) {
        // list.appendChild(imgs[i]);
        imgs[i].style.left = '-4000px';
    }
}, 3500);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezgux45b/)

I tried appending child but since that didn't work, I tried pushing them off the screen -- that didn't work either.
PS: I would appreciate a non-jQuery solution as I am trying to familiarize with javascript yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you change the css-property of the image:

```
.images {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This partial solution should give you the hint.
I've changed few thing to be more self explanatory.

Also note that there is used fixed size (64px) for the image container and images have own background color...

It is based on your fiddle.
[updated fiddle (with comments)](https://jsfiddle.net/ezgux45b/5/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src=img-1.jpg class=images alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src=img-4.jpg class=images alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src=img-3.jpg class=images alt="">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src=img-2.jpg class=images alt="">
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* this is the visible area */
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    height: 64px;
    width: 256px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
}
/* this element will shift to the left */
li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 64px;
    height: inherit;
}
li img {
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    /* to match the size of <li> element */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
li:nth-of-type(1) img {
    background-color: red;   
}
li:nth-of-type(2) img {
    background-color: green;   
}
li:nth-of-type(3) img {
    background-color: blue;   
}
li:nth-of-type(4) img {
    background-color: black;   
}
```

JS:

```
     // the list of <li> elements, these will shift from right to left
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
// this function is used to assign starting position to each <li> element
function init() {
    var pos, li;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        li = elements[i];
        // assign starting position to <li>
        // the first <li> will have position (0 * 64) = 0px from the left
        // the second <li> (1 * 64) = 64px
        // the third <li> (2 * 64) = 128px
        // etc.
        li.style.left = (i * 64) + 'px';
    }
}
// In this funciton we are moving each <li> by 64px to the left.
function slide() {
    var pos,    // this will hold the numeric value (number of px from the left)
        li,     // this will reference the <li>
        cssPos, // this will hold the CSS left position of the <li> element
        strNumPos   // this will hold the left position without px at the end (it is strill string value);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        // store the <li>
        li = elements[i];
        // get the CSS left position eg: "64px"
        cssPos = li.style.left;
        // get the numeric string value without "px" eg: "64"
        strNumPos = cssPos.replace('px', '');
        // convert the string to a number eg: 64
        pos = parseInt(strNumPos, 10);
        // since we are shifting each <li> by 64px to the left, it may happen that the
        // <li> would be pushed outside of the visible area eg: -64px to the left.
        // The visible area is a rectangle 256px wide.
        if (pos <= 0)
        {
            // The <li> would be pushed outside of the visible area so to create carousel effect
            // we will place the <li> at the end of the visible area.
            // the left position will be 196px
         pos = (elements.length - 1) * 64;   
        }
        else
        {
            // just update the position eg: 128 - 64 = 64
         pos = (pos - 64);   
        }
        // set new position to <li>
        li.style.left = pos + 'px';
    }
}
// start with arranging the layout
init();
// start the carousel effect
setInterval(slide, 1500);
```

**UPDATE**
The previous example is a bit evil and I will end up in hell for that :)
I've created a [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdcez6rj/6/) with simple carousel and minimum javascript.

The basic ideas is to use vanilla DOM method .appendChild() to append the first `<li>` at the end of the list.

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li"),
    ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

function slide() {
    // use appendChild() to simply append the first image at the end of the <ul>
    ul.appendChild(list[0]);
}
setInterval(slide, 1500);
```

Comment: thanks but I did not understand it. I guess it is something to complex for a beginner to attempt. I added some comments showing where I lost it here https://jsfiddle.net/nmeri17/ezgux45b/4/

Comment: Hello @CodeLama Sincere apologies for my inability to reply earlier. I've been trying to understand your code all this while but even though I still cant, I understand what you're trying to do. So I made something based on that in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nmeri17/wdcez6rj/2/ though it doesn't work. You can point out my error

Comment: Hi @Mmayboy your latest example contains few javascript errors like undeclared variables etc. In any case I've created another [SIMPLE fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdcez6rj/6/) with minimum javascript that works without these clumsy computations (I'm sorry for that).

Comment: surprised we never thought of this. Nevertheless I'll really be grateful if you can point out the errors and undefined variables in my fiddle as I'm looking to get better